# Missing GIt Repository tab in Java Eclipse with JBoss Tool

Tags: eclipse, jboss, eclipse-plugin, egit

I just installed Eclipse Java EE IDE in my Macbook. (Eclipse Version: Indigo Service Release 2
Build id: 20120216-1857).

I then installed JBoss Tool for Indigo. After that, I restarted Eclipse. Now from the "Installed Software" tab I can find "Name-JBoss Tools EGit Integration (Experimental) Version-2.3.1.v20120715-0255-H145-Final Id-org.jboss.tools.openshift.egit.integration.feature.feature.group". However, when I open Java EE perspective in Eclipse I couldn't find the "GIt Repository tab". I do have other tabs in the following sequence:
Markers --- Properties --- Servers --- Data Source Explorer --- Snippets

Can anyone provide any possible clue on why the Git Repository tab is missing even though the JBoss tool that includes it has been installed?

thanks!

Comment: Before installing jboss did you installed Git repository?

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you meant by "install Git Repository". I have Git installed in my Mac. And I think JBoss Tools includes the eGit Integration tool? Do you meant that besides installing Git, I need to install something else? thanks!

Comment: I see what you meant by install a Git repository now. Thanks.